# Como implementar este IF?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Debo implementar una esctructura de control para que cada vez que de click en un cuadro (DIV) cambie el color de fondo de rojo a negro y de negro a rojo cada vez que le de click

```js
jQuery(function(){ 
    
        function cambiacolor(bgcolor){                      
            jQuery('#a').css('background-color',bgcolor);   
            
            if (bgcolor === '#292c33') 
            {
                bgcolor = "#e21a1a";
            }
            else
            {
                bgcolor = "#292c33";
            }
    
            //Cookies.set('colorCookie',bgcolor);             
        }
    
        jQuery('#a').css('background-color','#292c33'/*Cookies.get('colorCookie')*/);
    
        jQuery('#a').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            colorseleccionado = jQuery(this).data('color');
            cambiacolor(colorseleccionado);     
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="a" class="celda" data-color="#e21a1a">1</div>
<div id="b" class="celda" data-color="#e21a1a">2</div>
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema que tienes? Por otra parte, ¿almacenar en las cookies el valor lo haces por algún requerimiento en concreto?

Comment: Debo cambiar de color de fondo un DIV cada vez que le de click y ese cambio guardarlo en cookies, es para una estanteria cuando este de color rojo quiere decir que esta libre y se puede guardar algo en ella y cuando este llena se le da click para decir que esta ocupada

tambien tengo la duda de como guardar diferentes posiciones https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/242794/como-podria-guardar-individualmente-cada-cuadro-en-cookies

Comment: ¿Es necesario guardar el color? ¿No te resulta mejor guardar el status (Disponible o Llena)?

Comment: Como puedo hacer eso?

Comment: Dame un minuto y formulo una respuesta

Comment: Puedes usar una clase que sea .llena { background-color: red; } y usar luego toggle para activarla o no, siendo el background-color por defecto, negro. O en lugar de toggle, hasClass para saber si la tiene y addClass o removeClass para ponerla o quitarla.

Comment: Si, como se usa el toggle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomendaría usar localStorage y clases, tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```js
var jQ = jQuery;
var estanteria = {};

jQ(document).ready(function(){

  jQ('.celda').each(function(){
    if(jQ(this).hasClass('llena'))estanteria[jQ(this).attr('id')] = 'llena';
    else estanteria[jQ(this).attr('id')] = 'vacia';
  });
  
  //localStorage.setItem('estanteria', JSON.stringify(estanteria));

  jQ('body').on('click', '.celda', function(){
    var id = jQ(this).attr('id');
    //estanteria = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('estanteria'));
    if(jQ(this).hasClass('llena')){
      estanteria[id] = 'vacia';
      jQ(this).removeClass('llena');
    }else{
      jQ(this).addClass('llena');
      estanteria[id] = 'llena';
    }
    console.log(estanteria);
    //localStorage.setItem('estanteria', JSON.stringify(estanteria))
  });
  
  //jQ('body').on('click', '#verLocalStorage', function(){
  
    //jQ('#contLocalStorage').html(localStorage.getItem('estanteria'));
  //});

});
```

```css
/*Aquí puedes colocar*/

.celda{
  background: #292c33;
}

.celda.llena{
  background: #e21a1a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="a" class="celda llena">1</div>
<div id="b" class="celda">2</div>

<button id="verLocalStorage">Ver localStorage</button>

<div id="contLocalStorage"></div>
```

No me deja colocar localStorage, pero podrás probarlo en tu entorno.

Dime si tienes alguna duda.

Comment: Usé jQ porque asumí que no podías usar $ (Por ejemplo si estás trabajando con Typescript o algo por el estilo)

Comment: Muchas gracias, fuinciona pero no me esta guardando los cambios

Comment: Qué aparece cuando colocas console.log(localStorage.getItem('estanteria')); ?

Comment: Dice que esta en 'null'

Comment: ¿Quitaste los comentarios de los localStorage? //localStorage.setItem('estanteria', JSON.stringify(estanteria));

Comment: No señor, eso fue el comentario 'No me deja colocar localStorage, pero podrás probarlo en tu entorno.' ?

Comment: Si jaja, tienes que quitar los comentarios.

Comment: O Des-comentar para ser preciso

Comment: Listo ya lo hice ahora en el console.log dice '{"a":"llena","b":"vacia","c":"vacia","d":"vacia","e":"vacia","f":"vacia"}' cuando hago cambios pero no guarda, en el almacenamiento local se ve el movimiento pero no los guarda solo se reinicia cuando recargo la pagina

Comment: ¿Cómo estás verificando si guarda? Recuerda que ahora los datos estarán guardados en localStorage.getItem('estanteria');, para usarlos debes hacer JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('estanteria'));  También es importante considerar que el each que puse es con los datos que vienen, podrías querer recorrer el localStorage en lugar de ese each: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('estanteria')).each(function(index, value){ alert(value); }); Si tienes dudas respecto de eso puedes formular una nueva pregunta, con gusto responderé.

Comment: Listo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243056/guardar-en-localstorage

Answer (score 3):

Yo lo plantearía con clases CSS:

1. Definiría dos clases (`libre` y `ocupada`) con el `background-color` deseado.
2. En el evento click de los elementos con clase `celda` usaría [togleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) para cambiar de una clase a otra.
3. A las `cookies` no les veo el sentido en este contexto.

```js
$(function(){ 

    function cambiacolor(div){                      
         $(div).toggleClass("libre ocupada");            
    }

    $('.celda').click(function(e){
        cambiacolor($(this));     
    });
});
```

```css
.ocupada{
  background-color: Red;
}

.libre{
  background-color: Green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<div id="a" class="celda ocupada">1</div>
<div id="b" class="celda libre">2</div>
```

Comment: Ey! me has hecho trampas xD

Comment: Había hecho la respuesta con hasClass, addClass y removeClass y para cuando he caído en el toggleClass ya he visto que lo tenías hecho XD. La voy a borrar porque no tiene sentiendo tener dos iguales :). Eso sí, ya que estás añade un snippet que funcione y algo de info sobre toggleClass

Comment: No la borres, estaría bien tener un ejemplo con hasClass, además, tu respuesta es más completa. Mejor borro la mía.

Comment: Me parece que el hasClass es mejor en esta situación, ya que necesita no solo cambiar la clase, sino que también usar localStorage. Pero es debatible.

Comment: Ah el localStorage o Cookies, puede tener sentido si está cargando contenido dinámicamente, si quiere reducir las llamadas a la base de datos o los procesos serverside, o si sencillamente está experimentando.