# Guardar en LocalStorage?

Tags: jquery

Cuando hay un cambio en la estanteria osea que cambie de vacia a llena deberia guardar el cambio pero No guarda los cambios efectuados. al recragar la pagina vuelve a su estado inicial

```
var jQ = jQuery;
var estanteria = {};

jQ(document).ready(function(){

  jQ('.celda').each(function(){
    if(jQ(this).hasClass('llena'))estanteria[jQ(this).attr('id')] = 'llena';
    else estanteria[jQ(this).attr('id')] = 'vacia';
  });

  localStorage.setItem('estanteria', JSON.stringify(estanteria));

  jQ('body').on('click', '.celda', function(){
    var id = jQ(this).attr('id');
    estanteria = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('estanteria'));
    if(jQ(this).hasClass('llena')){
      estanteria[id] = 'vacia';
      jQ(this).removeClass('llena');
    }else{
      jQ(this).addClass('llena');
      estanteria[id] = 'llena';
    }
    console.log(estanteria);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('estanteria'));
    localStorage.setItem('estanteria', JSON.stringify(estanteria))
  });

  jQ('body').on('click', '#verLocalStorage', function(){

    jQ('#contLocalStorage').html(localStorage.getItem('estanteria'));
  });

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="a" class="celda llena">1</div>
<div id="b" class="celda">2</div>
```

[image: no guarda]

Comment: Esto es totalmente cuestión de gustos, pero lo habitual es usar $ como *alias* de jQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En este código estás sobreescribiendo siempre el localStorage:

```
jQ('.celda').each(function(){
    if(jQ(this).hasClass('llena'))estanteria[jQ(this).attr('id')] = 'llena';
    else estanteria[jQ(this).attr('id')] = 'vacia';
  });
localStorage.setItem('estanteria', JSON.stringify(estanteria));
```

Hay que revisar si el localStorage no está vacío, y recorrer el mismo en lugar del DOM si es que corresponde, de la siguiente forma:

```
if(typeof localStorage.getItem('estanteria') === 'undefined' || localStorage.getItem('estanteria') == null){
jQ('.celda').each(function(){
  if(jQ(this).hasClass('llena'))estanteria[jQ(this).attr('id')] = 'llena';
    else estanteria[jQ(this).attr('id')] = 'vacia';
  });
localStorage.setItem('estanteria', JSON.stringify(estanteria));
}else{
  $.each(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('estanteria')), function(index, value){
  if(value == 'llena')$('#'+index).addClass('llena');
});
}
```

Dime si tienes alguna duda.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si funciona pero si recargo 2 veces se borran los registros del LocalStorage osea que ' estanteria = {} '

Comment: ¿Se borran completamente?

Comment: LocalStorage / ' estanteria = {} '

Comment: @SaulSalazar Corregí el código, localStorage.setItem('estanteria', JSON.stringify(estanteria)); debe ir dentro del primer if, dime si eso resuelve tu problema.

Comment: Excelente funciona perfecto, como puedo dar recompensa?

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica en que no cargas inicialmente lo que tienes en el localstorage. Lo que estás haciendo es que cada vez que recargas la página llenas el objeto `estanteria` con las celdas vacías y lo guardas. Para resolverlo tendrías que hacer algo como esto:

```
var estanteria = localStorage.getItem('estanteria') || {};
...
```

También veo que estás delegando eventos desde el `body`, lo cual no es un buena práctica debido a que va a escuchar cualquier click dentro del `body` y luego se evualuará si es que se ha hecho en un elemento con la clase `celda`.
Podrías cambiar esto:

```
jQ('body').on('click', '.celda', function(){
```

por esto:

```
jQ('.celda').on('click', function(){
```

O si de verdad necesitar delegar eventos porque las celdas se agregan dinámicamente, podrías cambiarlo por esto:

```
jQ('.celda-wrapper').on('click', '.celda', function(){
```

Que solo escuchará lo eventos dentro del padre directo de los elementos con la clase celda. Puedes leer más sobre la delegación de eventos [aquí](https://jfraguio.wordpress.com/2014/12/10/recorrer-el-dom-de-forma-eficiente-con-jquery-delegacion-de-eventos/).